# Why does my program says Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

I have a program that lets the user type the string and the delimiter, then the program will split the string according to the user's delimiter and will display the string in joption excluding the delimiter.

However the joption is not showing the output because the error says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
```

What should I do?

```
public ArrayList<String> token()
    {

       String str=txtString.getText().toString();
       String del=txtDelimiter.getText().toString();
       ArrayList <String> myTokens = new ArrayList <String> ();

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
       scan.useDelimiter(del);

       while(scan.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scan.next());
        myTokens.add(scan.next());
        }
       scan.close();
       return myTokens; 
    }
```

method called from another method:

```
btnShowTokens.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                ArrayList <String> stringpass=token();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, stringpass, "The posible tokens", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Adjusted code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Calling `next()` consumes the token from the Scanner. So here, each iteration of the loop tries to take two tokens from the scanner - one to print and one to add to `myTokens`. If you have an odd number of tokens, you'll get this exception.

A better approach would be to extract the token to a local variable and then use it wherever you need. E.g.:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String str = scan.next();
    System.out.println(str);
    myTokens.add(str);
}
```

Comment: The token is my method name btw:o

Comment: @benok probably not the greatest name for a local variable then. I've edited my answer to use `str` instead, just for clarity's sake, although it doesn't change the essence of the answer.